# Using bottom app bar as nested navigation in jetpack compse

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am stuck in a problem in jetpack compose navigation.
I do have a case where I have a full page screen like login/signup and other settings pages and on the home page, I need a bottom navigation bar. But from time to time I also need to move to a full-page screen like settings and all from the home page. How can I achieve it? does anyone have a rough idea or links to a solution or sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Use two NavHost. One is placed in the root for the full page screens, other is placed inside home page Scaffold.

Comment: Could you help review this? I have problem with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401623/navigating-to-a-bottom-tab-screen-from-a-single-screen-with-a-button-jetpack-com